# How to use the variable inside a button phrase outside?

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a program which would have a button, a label which gives me how-many times I've clicked the button. But the number is also required in some other places in the program. That's why I'm wondering how to apply the variable for the second time?

```
    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {



                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub\
                        number = 0;
                        number++;
                        .......
                    }

          });
     .......
    //String s = "good" + number;
    //jf.setText(s);
    // How to have the variable "number" be still avaliable here?

   }// end of some method...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    button2 t = new button2();
}
```

}

Comment: I would need to see more code in order to see where `number` is defined, but my guess is that `number` is available there. The issue is that you're resetting `number` to 0 every time the button is clicked, and then incrementing it by 1. Also, you're not resetting the `jf` text from within the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: how to reset the jf text?

Comment: You have the source `String s = "good" + number;` and `jf.setText(s);`, but they're outside of the `actionListener`. I would suggest commenting out `number = 0;`, and moving those two previous statements into the `actionListener` method.

Comment: but I need the renewed variable number outside of actionListener later~~

Comment: Yes, back to my previous comment, I would need to see more code to see where `number` is defined and how you intend to use it outside of the `actionListener`. You didn't define it locally (inside of the `actionListener`), so it must be defined elsewhere, like a class variable which would mean it should be accessible outside of the `actionListener` later.

Comment: The part where I defined String s and printed it was the part where I need the number out of the ActionListener~~

Comment: Without being able to see more, it looks like this code will only run once. It looks like it's an initialization method for your `JFrame` where you setup your buttons, add `actionListeners`, etc.. The only thing I would expect to run more than once is your `actionPerformed` method. Sure `String s` will be able to access `number`, but without seeing more code, my guess is that this will happen at program initialization. (guessing again) Once you update `number` by clicking your button, the `String s` statement won't run again.

Comment: import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class button2 extends JFrame{
 JPanel jp = new JPanel();
 JLabel jf = new JLabel();
 JButton jb = new JButton("push me");
 private int number;

Comment: Henry, please refer to my comment about this being an initialization method. I believe (where the source is commented out) this code was written to only be run once. In order to have you `jf` updated, it needs to happen once the button is clicked, and I believe those statements must be moved into the `actionListener` method, and that will resolve your issue. To answer your question, from the look of your program's design, you should be able to access `number` outside of the `actionListener`, but you must do so in a location where the source will be run more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `number` as a private field, and increase the value of `number` when the button is clicked. Your code will reset the value of `number` to 0 (zero), each time the button is clicked and then add 1 to it, resulting in `number` always being equal to 1.

```
private int number;

jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    number++;
  }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
  button2 t = new button2();
}
```

Comment: Note : non static variable can not be accessible inside actionPerformed-method.

Comment: Note: non static variable can be accessed inside actionPerformed-method because the application is object oriented. @jaolstad creates a button2() object inside of his `void main` which probably extends `JFrame`, having `number` as a private class variable. Your comment would be correct if his application didn't create a button2() object, and all of his source was inside of the `void main`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `number`  as a class/static variable, then you can access it.

refer likewise,

```
class SomeName{
private static int number = 0;
......

jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {



                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub\
                        number = 0;
                        number++; // here you can access number without any issue.
                        .......
                    }

          });

 .......
    String s = "good" + number; // here you can access number without any issue.
    jf.setText(s);

   }// end of some method...


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue with your application is that you want to access number during a the initialization of your `JFrame`, but you should be doing this in your `actionListener` method instead. The initialization should only run once, and when you click your button, it will not run again. Here's a code example of how this works:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class button2 extends JFrame {

    int num = 0;
    JButton b;
    JTextField jtf;

    public button2()
    {
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b = new JButton("Clickme");
        jtf = new JTextField("");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                num++;
                jtf.setText("good " + num);
                System.out.println("This prints every time I click the button");
            }
        });


        System.out.println("This only prints once");

        //String s = "good" + number;
        //jf.setText(s);  <--- Moved into the actionListener
        // How to have the variable "number" be still available here?

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        this.add(jtf);
        this.add(b);
        this.pack();
    }
    public static void main(String...banana) { new button2(); }
}
```